# Pandas line graph x-axis extra values

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have the following:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['time'].mean().unstack().plot()
```

This gives me a line graph like this one:

[image]

The circles in the plot indicate data points. The values on x-axis are the values of A which are discrete (100, 200 and 300). That is, I only have data points on the 100th, 200th and 300th point on the x-axis. Pandas/Matplotlib adds the intermediate values on the x-axis (125, 150, 175, 225, 250 and 275) that I *don't* want.

How can I plot and tell Pandas *not* to add the extra values on the x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Matplotlib x axis tick locators

You're looking for [tick locators](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html)

[image]

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
df = pd.DataFrame({'y':[1, 1.75, 3]}, index=[100, 200, 300])
ax = df.plot(legend=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(100))
```

Comment: Yes, you can change the MultiplesLocator to be any multiple you would like.
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(insert_multiple)

Comment: Thank you! I see, I am sorry that my simplified example gave the impression that my data are multiple of 100s. They are, in fact, not a multiple of a particular number. They include the number 1, 20, 30 etc.

Comment: There are many locators that can be found to suit many needs. Used FixedLocator with your own defined array of x values if nothing else fits nicely to your data. ax.set_xticks([array]) is a convenience wrapper for FixedLocator. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html